# How to add namespaces to a tag using Groovy's MarkupTemplateEngine

Tags: groovy

Is there a way to have a tag with a namespace using MarkupTemplateEngine?

I would like to be able to do something like this:
   sp.setNameSpaceDeclaration('http://example.org/myns')

```
 xmlDeclaration()

 cars(sp.ns) {
     cars.each {
       car(make: it.make, model: it.model)
       sp.brand(attribute:'year', 'my text')
     } 
  }
```

and get

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<cars xmlns:sp="http://example.org/myns">
    <car make='Peugeot' model='508'/>\
    <sp:brand attribute='year'>my text</sp:brand>
    <car make='Toyota' model='Prius'/>
    <sp:brand attribute='year'>my text</sp:brand>
</cars>
```

I found a way to tweak the template to get the result I wanted. There might be better solutions, but for now I am using:

```
 xmlDeclaration()
 cars('xmlns:sp':"http://example.org/myns") {
   cars.each {
      car(make: it.make, model: it.model)
     'sp:brand'(attribute:'year', 'my text')
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. I have included the StreamingMarkupBuilder initialization for completeness

```
def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'

def cars = builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    namespaces << [sp:'http://example.org/myns']
    cars('xmlns:sp':"http://example.org/myns") {
       cars.each {
          car(make: it.make, model: it.model)
         'sp:brand'(attribute:'year', 'my text')
       }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks sbglasius!  I do want to use the MarkupTemplateEngine though, since it allows to have the  template as a separate  template and include nested templates.
I will post what I am doing as answer, although your solution works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use a template file, so the way I am handling this for now is:

**cars.tpl** Template:

```
 xmlDeclaration()
 cars('xmlns:sp':"http://www.w3schools.com/furniture") {
   comment commentTest
   newLine()
   cars.each {
      car(make: it.make, model: it.model)
      newLine()
      'sp:brand'(attribute:'year', 'my text')
      newLine()
   }
}
```

Program

```
    URL url = this.getClass().getResource("/cars.tpl");
    File markupTemplate = new File(url.getFile());

    TemplateConfiguration config = new TemplateConfiguration();
    config.setAutoNewLine(true);
    config.setAutoIndent(true);
    config.setDeclarationEncoding('UTF-8');
    MarkupTemplateEngine engine = new MarkupTemplateEngine(config);

    Template template = engine.createTemplate(markupTemplate);
    def model = [commentTest: 'alberto', cars: [new Car(make: 'Peugeot', model: '508'), new Car(make: 'Toyota', model: 'Prius')]]

    def fout = new File("C:\\code\\cesa\\src\\test\\resources\\cars.xml")
    fout.withWriter('UTF-8') {writer ->
        template.make(model).writeTo(writer)
    }
```